# I would like to know the story of Kesari, the father of Hanumanji

Tags: vedas, ramayana, rama, hanuman

We know Kesari was a powerful being. Recently I came across an article on Bharatpedia.org and I came to know that he was a chief in the Vanara sena and fought Ravana's army. I am curious to know what was his role in the war and how did he die? In the war or due to natural causes?